# iText page-break-after doesn't work

Tags: pdf, itext

We have procured the iText HTML to PDF licence and we are trying to convert the HTML to PDF. We are facing issues in page breaking. As per documentation, we are using below css style but it doesn't work at all. We are using 7.1 version

```
<table style="border: solid 1pt; page-break-after: always" cellspacing="0">
```

Can you please help?

Comment: iText 7.1 isn't released yet, so please double-check the iText version number. Also, if you convert HTML to PDF, please know that pdfHTML was released for iText 7.0.2, *not* for iText 7.0.1. Finally, the `page-break-after` functionality is described in [the documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css). I can confirm that `page-break-after` works as expected for the example in the tutorial *using the latest SNAPSHOT of pdfHTML*. *Conclusion:* I think that you aren't using the correct versions of iText/pdfHTML.

Comment: Also please be aware that the Terms of Use of Stack Overflow do not allow using this service as a customer support system. You can ask questions about iText here, but your question is a *customer support* question, and therefore it's not eligible for Stack Overflow. You should use the official iText ticketing system instead. The moment you became a customer, you have received the option to get a log-in to iText's JIRA web-site. Please use your JIRA account to get more details about what I wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer support question. Customer support questions are not allowed as per the Terms of Use of Stack Overflow.